# How to search a table in R?

Tags: r

I have a table with 20 specific keys. I have another table with all the keys; each key has a description. I am interesting in searching each of the 20 keys in the second table and print their description. I was wondering if someone could give me general ideas or functions, so that I can start prototyping code.

Thank you!

Comment: if you want an answer its probably best you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) otherwise it will be hard for people to help

Answer (score 0):

I did some further research, and I figured it out. I need to use:

```
subset(data_frame, all_keys %in% keys)
```